# pandas string module slowing things

Tags: python, string, performance, pandas

I am using pandas for some data analysis and trying to speed up my analysis. When I profile my function using %prun in python I see:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.017    0.017 <string>:1(<module>)
   26    0.000    0.000    0.015    0.001 frame.py:2107(__setitem__)
```

These two items are mainly causing the slow down as you can see. I am new to pandas some insight into what these are and how to reduce this time would help.

thanks

Comment: It would help to see some actual code, example input, and expected output.

Comment: Hmm wondering how to do that since the code is rather lengthy and a minimal example would not reproduce the result. In summary though I am passing a dictionary of pandas dataFrames per record and computing a bunch of statistics on those records in the dictionary. My main question is what is pandas doing with the string module? and why is it so slow?

Comment: you are misinterpreting the output of prun; prun measure starting with parsing the command (which takes almost no time); but it's at the top of the call tree so it's cumtime includes all lower calls. separately, w/o showing code it is impossible to diagnose anything